# How to require a file in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code, not Visual Studio.

I have 2 files in the same folder.

I have one called

`Main.cs`

```cs
using System;
namespace csharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And another file called
`Person.cs`

```cs
using System;
class Person {
    string name = "";
    static void talk(Person person) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello! My name is {person.name}!");
    }
}
```

I want to call `Person.cs` in `Main.cs`, but I cant find out how, theres some solutions saying to use `include`, but it just doesn't work for me. Or people say to use one of Visual Studio's C# functions, which I'm not using. Visual Studio Code is what I use. Visual Studio Code ≠ Visual Studio. My VSC folder/workspace is structured like this:

```
csharp.csproj
|
Main.cs
|
Person.cs
|
bin-(debug files)
|
obj-(debug files)
```

Comment: When they are in the same namespace, just create a new `Person` object in your `Program`. It now depends on the compiler... If you are using `csc` you have to tell `csc` which files to include in the assembly. ..... You `Person.talk` method is private though... Your should change it to public. And... You should not make `Person.talk` static. It does not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Person` class is not in a namespace, so it defaults to the `global` namespace. You should be able to access it with `global::Person`.However, you could also put it in the same namespace like your `Program` class. Then you can use it directly.

Please note, that the `talk` method is `private` if you do not declare it otherwise. You have to declare it `public` or `internal` to be able to access it from outside of the class `Person`.

```
using System;

namespace csharp
{
    class Person {
        string name = "";
        public static void talk(Person person) {
            Console.WriteLine($"Hello! My name is {person.name}!");
        }
    }
}
```

If you put the class in a different namespace, you can use the `using` directive to access it.

```
using YourNamespace;
```